# Are custom fonts that I add to my iOS app available to other apps on the device?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

I have proprietary custom fonts in my iOS app and I'm wondering whether other apps can use my font after the app has been installed on a device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. As the other apps can't access your app's bundle resources, they can't use your custom font.

Since It's not possible to access other app bundle details, there is no document available since now.

But you can learn more about `NSBundle` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.5/Reference/Frameworks/ObjC/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle/Description.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBundle) and about Accessing a Bundle's Content [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW1).

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find reference to that information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can get your assets like , Appicons, Launch Image, Fonts any mp3/mp4 file that all added as Assets.
Now, How can we get this...
for Example,

Download an App through Mac Itunes --> Right Click & Open in Folder --> Copy IPA to Dektop --> Now Change .IPA extension to .ZIP & Extract the converted ZIP file --> OPen FOlder --> Right Click on App & Click on Show Package Contents --> It will shwo you the Assets Used in Apps

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 13, apps can make use of a new Fonts entitlement, namely `Install fonts`. Apps that use the related API are called 'font provider apps'. Examples of such apps are *CreativeCloud* from Adobe and *MyFonts* from MonoType.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/